# Find Stability-Function and -Interval of Runge Kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, runge-kutta-methods

We're given this Butcher Tableau

$$
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
1 & 1\\
\hline
& \frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} 
\end{array}$$

We want to:

1. Write it as a one-step process
2. Find its stability-function and -interval

Comment: For readers like me who know Runge-Kutta  but not Butcher's tableaux : https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/02/13/runge-kutta-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The one step process is:
   $$k_1=f(t_k, y_k)$$
   $$k_2=f(t_k + h, y_k + hk_1)$$
   $$y_{k+1}=y_k + \frac{h}{2}(k_1 + k_2)$$
2. For the stability function, we let 
   $f(t_k, y_k) = \lambda y_k$ and $f(t_k + h, y_k + hk_1) = \lambda (y_k + hk_1)$. 

    Thus $$y_{k+1} = y_k + \frac{h}{2}((\lambda y_k) + (\lambda (y_k + hk_1))) = y_k(1 + \lambda h + \frac{\lambda^2 h^2}{2})$$. Now, if $z := h \lambda$ then our stability function can be written as $$g(z) = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2}$$

    For the stability interval, we need $|g(z)| < 1$. In our case, we can rearrange that as $z + \frac{z^2}{2} < 0$ or $z(2+z) < 0$. Our stability interval is thus $-2 < z < 0$.

Comment: You missed a term. All explicit methods with stage number eq. order have the corresponding partial sum of the exponential series as stability function, you should get as with the Ralston method also with the Heun method $g(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}2$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah yeah right Thanks for pointing it out By the way, your feedback is greatly appreciated, especially during those troubling times.